# Write dataframe to a ".csv" file without specifying file path

Tags: r, csv, file-writing

Given this data frame as:

```
a <- 1:5
b <- 6:10
df <- data.frame(a,b)
df
```

Can I write to `.csv` file automatically without pre-creating such `.csv` file

```
write(df)
```

without specifying the file path (because I have no pre-created file) and r will create one *automatically* to save my data frame in my working directory?

Comment: Creating a csv file is not a problem, but you have to give that csv file a proper name. What do you want to call it then? Do you want it to be named randomly?

Comment: let me specify a name

Comment: I think you need to check whether you have write permission to your working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your question! you just use:

```
write.csv(df, "df.csv")
```

Comment: Error message: `cannot open file 'df.csv': No such file or directory`

Comment: What's your operating system, Windows, Linux, or MacOS? @DanielJames

Comment: I am operating on Windows

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom function that converts object name into a filename and saves as `".csv"`:

```
myWrite <- function(x){
  write.csv(x, file = paste0(deparse(substitute(x)), ".csv"))  
  }

myWrite(mtcars)

list.files(pattern = "mtcars")
# [1] "mtcars.csv"
```

Comment: Error: `Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection`

Comment: @DanielJames You either have no permission to create a file in current directory, or you have the existing CSV file open in Excel.